# How to stop IE11 from caching security context

Tags: single-sign-on, internet-explorer-11, ntlm

We have windows integrated SSO setup for our CMS platform but if our scheduled task to open IE 11 and load the CMS home page runs before the VPN is signed on then it doesn't get authenticated and we forward to another site. If I try to browse to intranet CMS site again after VPN is signed on it still won't work because IE11 caches security context. If I close IE11 and re-open and browse it does SSO just fine because security context is refreshed. Any idea how to override this in registry or something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the CMS website caches the vpn data and you can try to disable IE website cache to see if it works:

1. Click **Alt+X** to open the **Tools** panel in IE 11.
2. From the menu, select **Internet options**.
3. Click **Settings** in **Browsing history** section on the **General** tab.
4. On the **Temporary Internet Files** tab, confirm that **Every time I visit the webpage** is selected.

[image]

5. On the **Caches and databases** tab, confirm that **Allow website caches and databases** is not selected.

[image]

6. Click **OK** to apply the settings.

Comment: I think there's no other options as Internet Explorer performs a cleanup of the security contexts when the last instance of Internet Explorer is closed. As a workaround, you can arrange the scheduled task in another way: First, get your VPN to be connected, then after 1 or 2 minutes, launching the IE browser.

Comment: Yep that is what I told him to do. Launch after 10-20 sec basically